# How do I reference android:gravity values in a resource file?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with a `TextView` and I want the `android:gravity` attribute value to be pulled from another resource file, `android:gravity="@???/item_align"`, where `item_align` is the name of a resource in another xml file. The typical values used in a layout, `center` or `bottom` or `bottom|center_horizontal` don't work. What type goes in the `@???`, integer works, if I replace the strings with the actual integer value ("center" replaced with 0x011). But, that's not a good solution.

So, the question(s): How do I refer to the value in the layout file, and what does the item look like in the resource file?

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/item_text"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_margin="1dp"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:gravity="@???/item_align"
   android:text="65"
   android:textSize="20sp"
   android:typeface="sans"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Concept:**

```
 android:gravity="@integer/integer_name"
```

integers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer
        name="integer_name"
        >1</integer>
</resources>
```

Gravity values are all integer constanst, you have to look it up and define it in your integers.xml .


**Example implementation:**

> > public static final int CENTER ... Constant Value: 17 (0x00000011)

in [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html#CENTER)... Then you add to your integers.xml in res/values/:

```
 <integer
        name="center"
        >17</integer>
```

and in your xml, do:

```
android:gravity="@integer/center"
```

Comment: Should'nt use `attrs.xml` in this case...?

Answer (score 11):

Here you go.

```
<integer name="gravity_bottom">80</integer>
<integer name="gravity_center">17</integer>
<integer name="gravity_center_horizontal">1</integer>
<integer name="gravity_center_vertical">16</integer>
<integer name="gravity_end">8388613</integer>
<integer name="gravity_left">3</integer>
<integer name="gravity_no_gravity">0</integer>
<integer name="gravity_right">5</integer>
<integer name="gravity_start">8388611</integer>
<integer name="gravity_top">48</integer>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that doing it like this is a good idea. The resource values are correct, but the layout might misbehave if its LayoutParams don't support the type of Gravity you're giving it.

Answer (score 3):

In order not to break the standard constants and avoid highlighting in red in Android Studio, you can create two styles (in styles.xml) in the /values and /values-sw600dp folder

/values/styles.xml

```
 <style name = "AppContainerLayout">
     <item name = "android:gravity">top|start</item>
 </style>
```

/values-sw600dp/styles.xml

```
<style name = "AppContainerLayout">
    <item name = "android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

And just use in layout

```
<LinearLayout
             style = "@ style/AppContainerLayout"
             android:layout_width = "match_parent"
             android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
             android:orientation = "vertical">

             // childs
</LinearLayout>
```